# How to convert Date from "2016-01-27 11:39:07 PM" to "2016-01-27 11:39 PM" format using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

I want to remove seconds from a date string from the table for display purpose.

For example, `2016-01-27 11:39:07 PM`  should be `2016-01-27 11:39 PM`

How can I do that using SQL query?

I don't want to save in the table column, I need it as text in a column from a query, to see the data.

Comment: Do you mean you have a character column with values like that, with two dates?

Comment: Per the [tag:sql] tag: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2) being used" - unfortunately, date/time handling is *far* from standard across databases, so please edit and add the correct additional tag.

Comment: My Date format is "2016-01-27 11:39:07 PM" in table and i wand update date format:--   LIKE "2016-01-27 11:39:07 PM  To  2016-01-27 11:39 PM"

Comment: @DevRana - repeating substantially the *same* words multiple times isn't clarifying things. If we're not sure why you keep saying `"2016-01-27 11:39:07 PM To 2016-01-27 11:39 PM"`, saying it again doesn't help us.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And what data **type** is that column?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you would need to create your own function for such a format or other special formats.
You can find information about creating custom format dates with custom functions in these articles:

- http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/display-dates-format-you-need
- http://kharismaworld.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/how-to-format-and-convert-datetime-in.html

Also you could us multiple `SUBSTRING` functions on your date and concatenate the parts to get your desired format.